# Prestashop 1.7.6.3 calculates tax in wrong way

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In `prestashop 1.7.6.3`, the tax is calculated in the wrong way.I need to round the unit price after it derived from base price having discount. Now the price and total excluding tax is ok but price and total including tax is not right for that rouding. How can i round that? I tried
in product.php

```
$specific_price_reduction = 0;
    if (($only_reduc || $use_reduc) && $specific_price) {
        if ($specific_price['reduction_type'] == 'amount') {
            $reduction_amount = $specific_price['reduction'];

            if (!$specific_price['id_currency']) {
                $reduction_amount = Tools::convertPrice($reduction_amount, $id_currency);
            }

            $specific_price_reduction = $reduction_amount;

            // Adjust taxes if required

            if (!$use_tax && $specific_price['reduction_tax']) {
                $specific_price_reduction = $product_tax_calculator->removeTaxes($specific_price_reduction);
            }
            if ($use_tax && !$specific_price['reduction_tax']) {
                $specific_price_reduction = $product_tax_calculator->addTaxes($specific_price_reduction);
            }
        } else {
            $specific_price_reduction = $price * $specific_price['reduction'];
        }
    }

    if ($use_reduc) {
        $price -= $specific_price_reduction;
    }

    // Group reduction
    if ($use_group_reduction) {
        $reduction_from_category = GroupReduction::getValueForProduct($id_product, $id_group);
        if ($reduction_from_category !== false) {
            $group_reduction = $price * (float) $reduction_from_category;
        } else { // apply group reduction if there is no group reduction for this category
            $group_reduction = (($reduc = Group::getReductionByIdGroup($id_group)) != 0) ? ($price * $reduc / 100) : 0;
        }

        $price -= $group_reduction;
    }
```

I checked `classes/cart.php`, `classes/cartrule.php` and several other files but it also didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

in your config/config.inc.php line 134, you can change 2 constants about price precision.

```
define('_PS_PRICE_DISPLAY_PRECISION_', 5);
define('_PS_PRICE_COMPUTE_PRECISION_', 5);
```

Note:
i put 5 by example

Comment: But this removes round from all the prices. I need to round unit price excludes tax then tax should be added to it. And for price includes tax it should be rounded.

Comment: then in your order process, look for this constants and change it just in the order process

Comment: Now exactly what i need to do is rounding the unit price (specific price enabled) before multiplying with tax rate. Can u please help me?

Comment: please, edit your post to show us your code and give the name of file that you override and the exact version of your 1.7

Comment: can you  also give the template file(s) concerned please